# Word for "having a lot of irregular bumps"?

Tags: single-word-requests

[image]

I'm looking for a word to describe the bark of a tree or the inner walls of an intestine — specifically, their random and irregular patterns of bumps. Any suggestions?

Comment: the answer is simply "bumpy" !

Comment: you know, you deal with this sort of thing a lot if you make, like, 3d movie models or models for video games.  I really can't think of a word that specifically means the surface geometry is "irregularly bumpy".  it's possible **modulated** or **undulating** could help.

Comment: (although it is true that "undulating" comes from "waves", which mathematically couldn't be less irregular/random: my same criticism of "furrowed" or "corrugated".)

Comment: Could someone please reduce the size of this image? I find it quite unnerving.

Comment: I like the image this big!  Could you add a movable 3D version? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be a single word for both contexts?

For tree bark I might go with [gnarled](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gnarled), but at least for me that carries connotations of hardness that wouldn't suit intestines.

For complex soft surfaces I've sometimes used [convoluted](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/convoluted), but that may not be specifically-bumpy enough...

Answer (score 2):

[Furrowed:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rugged)  may fit: (from TFD)

> - having long narrow shallow depressions (as grooves or wrinkles) in the surface; "furrowed fields"; "his furrowed face lit by a warming smile"

or  [rugged](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rugged)  ( from TFD)

> - Having a rough irregular surface, rough.
> - Having strong features marked with furrows or wrinkles: the rugged face of the old sailor.

also [corrugated:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/corrugated) ( bit more formal , it may be used to describe the surface of internal body parts like throat or intestine)

> - corrugated - shaped into alternating parallel grooves and ridges; "the surface of the ocean was rippled and corrugated"

Comment: For me furrowed strongly implies **regularity** and corrugated somewhat implies **regularity**.

Answer (score 1):

*Protrusions*, and *protuberances* would also be appropriate. They are all synonyms for bumps, but they sound more impressive. They need not be regular, but neither do bumps.

Trees can have groups of knotted **protrusions** which are called [burls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burl)

[image]

For intestines, **protuberances** is perhaps preferred.

> The tiny protuberances that line the small intestines are called villi and microvilli.

Source: [answers.com](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_are_the_tiny_protuberances_that_line_the_small_intestine)

Finally, the bumps on a human skull can be called protuberances

> if it be true, that certain *protuberances* of the skull are found in
>   numerous individuals, and each of these individuals are remarkable for
>   the possession of given qualities or dispositions of mind—and, if it
>   be true, that a number of persons are found wanting in the same
>   qualities of mind, and, at the same time, destitute of the first
>   mentioned *protuberances* of the skull—it is perfectly justifiable,
>   after a sufficiently extensive examination has been made to decide
>   upon the general rule, to declare that the *protuberance* is a correct
>   indication of the mental quality;

[The anatomy and physiology of the human body](http://books.google.it/books?id=U8ZLAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA164&dq=protuberances&hl=en&sa=X&ei=q1FTVIqRBIPgaO2AgZAM&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=protuberances&f=false) (1827)

Comment: I completely agree that this is a great word **when describing, medically, the human body**.  However - I'm guessing baed on Jano's other questions over the years - Jano is talking about describing a surface in a computer-gamey sense. (Of course, I'm not certain of that.)

Comment: @JoeBlow he's talking about trees and intestines. There's even a picture. If it's computer graphics, why can't he say that?

Comment: "I'm looking for a word to describe the bark of a tree or the inner walls of an intestine"  "specifically, their **random and irregular patterns of** bumps".   "Protrusions" and "protuberances" are, basically, bumps.  Jano might have asked: "specifically, their **random and irregular patterns of** Protrusions".  Or, "specifically, their **random and irregular patterns of** protuberances".

Comment: "he's talking about trees and intestines", it seems he's talking about 'tree bark' or 'the inner walls of intestines'.

Comment: @JoeBlow Yes. And stop being picky, it doesn't become you. :)

Comment: (LOL!)  "Word for “having a lot of irregular bumps”?" ... I've got it: protuberancesque or protrusionistic.  Howzat?

Comment: Not sure about your latest brainwave, *protruded* would be more fitting, altho it sounds a bit rude... *protuberant* is the adjective.

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

- ***rough***: *having an uneven or irregular surface; not smooth or level.*
- ***knobby***: *full of or covered with knobs (also **knobbly** and **lumpy**)*
- ***scabrous***: *rough and covered with, or as if with, scabs.*

Comment: Rough material is *not* bumpy. *Knobby* makes me laugh, it's more informal than *bumpy*. *Scabrous*, a scabrous tree? Maybe. But a scabrous intestine makes me wince in pain.

Comment: You've never run your hands over the *rough bark* of a tree? You're missing out! If *knobby* made you laugh, wait til I add *lumpy*.

Answer (score 1):

A tree is ***barky***, of course. Some trees have smooth bark and some rough.

And the inner surface of small intestine is ***villous***. (Because the inner walls are covered with [villi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intestinal_villus))

<sub>[Note: The picture in the question is not the inner surface of intestines but esophagus]</sub>

The problem here is you are asking for two very different kind of surfaces under a very general question title.

The first issue is the texture. For example, there are different textures of bark. Tree barks usually have ridges but not bumps. A tree bark cannot be called bumpy in general (except in technical context if there is a bumpy-like appearance on the surface). So in general, you might go with *barky* or *rough* for trees.

The second issue is hardness. *Rough* is usually used for hard surfaces so we cannot use it for intestine. Inner walls of small intestine have a ***convoluted*** villous structure. Large intestine lacks villi but it also has a convoluted structure.

The only common adjective for surfaces that does not connote any hardness level and can be applied to very different kind of textures is ***uneven*** itself.

Comment: You are probably aware of this, but villi are very tiny. The visible folds are [plicae circulares](http://www.histology.leeds.ac.uk/digestive/small_intestine.php)

Answer (score 1):

The inner walls of the small intestine are described as **folded** ([Children's Hospital of Pittsburg](http://www.chp.edu/CHP/organs+intestine)) and **wrinkled** ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_intestine#Absorption)):

> The small intestine has three features which allow it to have such a huge absorptive surface area packed into a relatively small space:
>
> Mucosal **folds**: The inner surface of the small intestine is not flat, but thrown into circular folds. This not only increases the surface area, but helps regulate the flow of digested food through your intestine...

Other words that are synonyms to the adjective *folded* include

- furrowed
- ridged
- crumpled
- rippled
- undulated
- wavy
- creased

and all of these word can describe the folds on the inner wall of the intestine and the surface of tree bark. These words encompass not just the bumps, but also the dimples, craters, and creases in between the bumps, and thus describe the whole surface.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to really **specifically** describe such a surface, I guess **perturbations** will be relevant.

(ie, you would describe the perturbations in some specific way in each case.)

Fundamentally you start with a given surface (either flat, or regular sine-wave like), then "modulate" it overall, perhaps using lower frequency and/or random modulation.  And/or and random individual perturbations (such as **perlin noise** - just google).

Note that tree bark, versus the image you show (nominally, intestines) are quite different.

In tree bark there are short length-wise perturbations (about 1% of the diameter in width and 5% of the diameter in length).  In the intestine image there are fairly regular (perhaps "slightly modulated" in wavelength and height) circular wave-like troughs which have a height about 5% of the diameter.

Comment: You mean that you could have a perturbed throat or intestine?

Comment: That would seem to be a totally different use of the word in a different context. Here we are talking about describing a surface.  It happens to be the surface of a "CGI rendering suggesting a animal intestine."  Note that the first sentence of my answer (even using bold) says in crisp English "trying to specifically describe such a surface".